# Datalist is empty while API return values

Tags: javascript, php, html-datalist

I'm using dynamic datalist to show cities when full zipcode is written in input. For some reasons, some zipcode show all cities, but some others don't show anything, even if the API i'm using return values.

My API call :

```php
$codePostal = $_REQUEST["zipcode"];
$cURLConnection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL,'https://geo.api.gouv.fr/communes?codePostal=' . $codePostal . '&fields=nom&format=json&geometry=centre');
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$list = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);
$jsonArrayResponse = json_decode($list, true);
$citiesStr = "";
$names = [];
foreach ($jsonArrayResponse as $items) {
    if (isset($items["nom"])) {
        $names[] = $items["nom"];
    }
}

$uniqueNames = array_unique($names);
asort($uniqueNames);

echo json_encode($uniqueNames);
```

My JS file where I choose to add cities when full zipcode is written :

```js
this.zipcodeInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
    if (this.zipcodeInput.value.length === 5) {
        this.loadCities(this.zipcodeInput.value).then(cities => {
            const citiesParse = JSON.parse(cities);
            for (let i = 0; i < citiesParse.length; i++) {
                const cityOption = document.createElement("option");
                cityOption.value = citiesParse[i];
                this.cityDatalist.appendChild(cityOption);
             }
        })
    } else {
        [...this.cityDatalist.childNodes].forEach(child => child.remove());
    }
});
```

My input with datalist for cities :

```html
<div class="step-field" data-type="birth" data-optional="0" data-label="' . $nativeCityWording . '" data-identifier="native-city">
    <label>' . $nativeCityWording . '</label>
    <input list="listCities" id="native_city" name="native-city" class="form-text form-input input">
    <datalist id="listCities">
    </datalist>
</div>
```

And here is the data I got after my API call and processing data :

```json
["Allouis","Berry-Bouy","Fo\u00ebcy","Marmagne","Mehun-sur-Y\u00e8vre","Sainte-Thorette","Vignoux-sur-Barangeon"]
```

I got no problem with encoding, the number of `<option>` have no impact, except for performance, but it's doesn't matter as it's about 0.2s of loading.

But for no reasons, the API calls with some zipcodes return data, but it's not added in datalist...

### Edit

I forgot to say that I'm calling results in my PHP file, with an AJX Request in my JS file :

```js
loadCities(zipcode) {
   return ajx(public_url + "assets/geodata/city-list.php?zipcode=" + zipcode);
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm if _any_ dataset returned from the API with Unicode escape sequences `\u00..` are added to the select list?

Comment: Yes, the list I gave work, I can see it in datalist

Comment: OK. Can you isolate _where_ the problem is occurring? You mentioned the API is returning a result. Is PHP returning the JSON encoded string OK? Is your AJAX call receiving that? Is `JSON.parse` working OK? Is it going into your _for_ loop?

Comment: From what I can see, when I'm on the page, and I change the zipcode input, with some zipcode, I got no cities in datalist. And with your questions, I can see I forgot to mention smthg... ^^

I'm doing the API call in a php file, then I do an ajax call in my JS file to get the data receive in PHP file. It's not a lot, but at least you got everything : 
```javascript
loadCities(zipcode) {
    return ajx(public_url + "assets/geodata/city-list.php?zipcode=" + zipcode);
}
```

This is the part u'r missing, I'll add it in post ^^

Comment: So, if I open the browser console, after changing the zipcode, I can see the answer from the PHP call, and I got an JSON answer, with the cities. But it's just not appearing in datalist

Comment: OK, add some debugging statements (`alert(...)` or `console.log(...)`) in your response handler to try to isolate exactly where it is going wrong. Also try to ensure `this.cityDatalist` is still a valid reference and not null by the time the response comes back.

Comment: After adding A LOT of console.log, it's looks like it don't go in the for loop, for some zc... I don't know why, because some zc with lower or higher length work... So it's not a pb of `citiesParse.length` ...

Comment: Try `console.log(citiesParse);` What does that look like for the zip that doesn't work? Is this reproducible for the same zip code?

Comment: So you got it, I got an array with the working zip, and I got object with not working zip